# Using a string value as an attribute

Tags: c#

I want to loop through a collection of string values and insert them as attributes. Something like this:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    var one = result.GetStuff();
    var two = result.Find(one);
    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        one.Properties["something"].Value = two.something;
    }
}
```

'users' is a collection of string values. Where you see "something" (two places), I want to be using a string value from 'users'. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

If you set the key type to a `string` type, this will allow you to do as your code example, though the value types need to belong to one type.

See [this page](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys) for information on how to use dictionaries in .NET (thanks @Filip Ekberg).

Answer (score 0):

`one.Properties[user.SomeStringValue]`

Comment: @spud, you can combind this with the answer from @Oded.